# Cannot access protected property CI_Output::enable_profiler

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am upgrading my site from an old version of codeigniter to new one but I got an error "Cannot access protected property CI_Output::enable_profiler" during upgrade. I know that the property enable_profiler has been protected in new versions. But I do not know how can I access this property in my controller/model. I do not want to change my existing code. Following is my code

```
if($this->output->enable_profiler)
{
   .......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the CI doc you can use the following method to enable disable profiling

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);// to enable

$this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE); // to disable
```

[profiling](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html)

Comment: I do not want to enable or disable profiler. I want to check if a profiler is enabled or disabled. $this->output->enable_profiler property returns true or false to tell that the profiler is enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The return type is void for `$this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE);` In `class CI_Output`

```
/**
 * Enable/disable Profiler
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   bool
 * @return  void
 */
function enable_profiler($val = TRUE)
{
    $this->enable_profiler = (is_bool($val)) ? $val : TRUE;

    return $this;
}
```